# Insert a document containing a field from another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these 2 models:

Role model (Role.js)

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");

const roleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    role: {
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    description : {
        type : String,
        required : true         
    } 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Role", roleSchema);
```

I populate the Role collection:

```
db.Roles.insertMany([{_id: 1, description: "Read only"}, { _id: 2, description: "Read, write" }, { _id: 3, description: "Read, write, delete" }])
```

Admin model  (Admin.js)

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
const Role = require("./Role");

const adminSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName : { 
        type : String,    
        required : true
    },
    lastName : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    dateCreate : { 
        type : Date, 
        default : Date.now 
    }, 
    role : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "Role"
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Admin", adminSchema);
```

As you can see, the Admin model contains a field that is a reference to the Role _id in Role.js

Now I'm trying to insert a document in the Admin collection.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Test")
 
insertAdmin()
async function insertAdmin() { 
    try {       
        const role = Role.findOne({_id: 3});
        console.log("Role: " + role)

        const admin = await Admin.create({
            firstName : "Kate",
            lastName : "Eagan",
            email : "vvv@dd.com",
            role : role._id            
        })

        console.log("Admin added");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
        console.log("Admin NOT added");
    }

    //console.log(admin);
}
```

All goes well, the admin is added, but when I do (using mongosh) :

```
db.admins.find()
```

all the admins have no role field, it's just not showing. I guess I'm not inserting it correctly in my `insertAdmin()` function?

Comment: I think you need to `await` the `findOne()` since you're trying to use the result afterwards

Comment: It seems that was it. But now it gives a ``Cast to ObjectId failed for value "3" (type number) at path "_id" for model "Role"``. I also kept getting this message when hardcoding a number for Role

Comment: Should your `findOne()` be filtering on `role` (which is a number in your schema) rather than `_id` (which probably defaults to a different type of ObjectId)?

Comment: @user20042973 I just want it to return the role, which is an integer that describes roles. Actually, I tried changing my role in the model to ``_id``, with the intent of overwriting the mongoose _id

Comment: In `Admin` model, you have define reference to Role as `ObjectId` but still insert role with _id as integer so it cannot populate correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-created your work here [GitHub](https://github.com/hichammounadi/admin-role)

it just worked perfectly, seems that the problem is that when you try to assign the founded id of the role to the new admin that you want to create, it comes with `**ObjectId**(xxxxxxxxxx)` prefix and in that way it don't work as far as I know, you can check, another thing, can anyone knows the difference between

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId
```

and

```
mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

and one more thing to add is that if the role is required in the admin model you should add the option, so that you can check it with your existing code.

Comment: Thanks Hicham. I'm impressed you went though all that to help. Cheers mate